Prove that $\det(A^{38}-I)>0$
This is a follow up of Prove that $A^{19}=A+I_3\implies\det(A^{38}-I_3)>0$, asked 3 hours ago by @shehbaz-thakur and soon closed (including by me) for lack of context.

Suppose it is given that $$A^{19}=A+I$$ where $A$ is a $3×3$ matrix with real entries and $I$ is the $3×3$ identity matrix. Prove that $$\det(A^{38}-I)>0$$

$A^{19}=A+I$
$\implies A^{19}\cdot A^{19}=(A+I)(A+I)$
$\implies A^{38}=A^2+2A+I$
$\implies A^{38}-I=A(A+2I)$
$\implies \det(A^{38}-I)=\det(A)\cdot\det(A+2I)$
$\implies \det(A^{38}-I)=\det(A^{19}-I)\cdot\det(A^{19}+I)$
After this I am stuck. Any help is greatly appreciated.

And $A\in M_3(\Bbb R)$.

@AnneBauval real entries

Your final line is immediate from difference of squares: $A^{38}-I = (A^{19}-I)(A^{19}+I)$

We know that $A$ has a real eigenvalue $\lambda$ since its characteristic polynomial has odd degree. Then using $A^{19}v = Av + v$ for the corresponding eigenvector means $\lambda^{19} = \lambda + 1$, which implies $\lambda > 0$. Now use the Jordan canonical form in $\mathbb{C}$. We either get $1$ or $3$ Jordan blocks. :)

@SarahBrooks Please don't answer in comments. Post an answer if you like.

@AnneBauval It's just a (generous) hint.

THANK YOU OP for properly motivating this question--not seen enough on MSE. +1

You may show $\det(A)>0$ and $\det(A+2I)>0$ separately. If $A^{19}=A+I$, $A$'s eigenvalues are zeros of $p(x)=x^{19}-x-1$. Note that $p(x)$ has only one positive (real) root. Since $A$ is a $3\times 3$ matrix, we have $\det(A)=\lambda_1\lambda_2\lambda_3$. For every other complex eigenvalue, it would come as $\lambda_2=\overline{\lambda_3}$, i. e. $\lambda_2\lambda_3=|\lambda_2|^2>0$. Hence, the product is positive.
Since $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, $\lambda+2$ is an eigenvalue of $A+2I$. You may repeat the argument.

You did not explain how the fact that elements of $A$ are real enters your solution.

Well, in that case $\det(A)$ would potentially be complex, so the question wouldn't make sense. I assumed real entries. If $A$ has complex entries, the eigenvalues do not necessarily come in conjugate pairs. That's where I used the said assumption.

Well but why can't the equation $\det(A)=\lambda_1^3$ be true, where $\lambda_1$ is a real root of $p(x)$? Yes indeed then $\lambda_1$ must be real [and thus as $p(x)$ is as it is] positive and the result still holds. But there is still more work to be done here.

The characteristic polynomial $\chi_A(x)$ has real coefficients and degree $3$, hence has at least one real root $\lambda$. Every root of $\chi_A(x)$ is a root of the minimal polynomial  hence also of $P(x):=x^{19}-x-1$. Since $P(x)$ has only one real root $\lambda$, the three roots of $\chi_A(x)$ are $\lambda,z,\bar z$ for some $z\in\Bbb C\setminus\{0,-2\}$ (which may be $\lambda$).
Therefore, $$\det(A^2+2A)=(\lambda^2+2\lambda)(z^2+2z)(\bar z^2+2\bar z)=(\lambda^2+2\lambda)|z^2+2z|^2,$$ which is positive because $\lambda$ is.

How did you find the characteristic polynomial?? How did you find $\det(A-\lambda I)$?

I didn't need to.

I am not able to understand your solution from the very beginning. Can you pls write some explanations too for the statements you wrote?

I'm not sure you have to separate the cases $\lambda,\lambda,\lambda$ and $\lambda,z,\overline z$

@J.W.Tanner Thank you for this improvement.

Is ${0,-2} $ a standard notation for a segment?

It’s a set with two elements

@user Indeed. Moreover, note that $\lambda$, though belonging to the segment,  was explicitely allowed.

@AnneBauval  I cannot follow the argument. From your description I would expect $z\in \lambda \cup\mathbb C \setminus \mathbb R$.

@user this is also true. What cannot you follow?

The reason for exclusion of only two points instead of the whole real axis.

@user We need to exclude $0$ and $-2$ because we want to prove $\det(A^{38}-I)>0$, not only $\ge0$. And the real number $\lambda$ must not be excluded.

But you have already stated that $z\not\in\mathbb R$, unless $z=\lambda$. This means particularly that $z\ne 0,-2$.  And any real value in between would be even worser.

Again, @user: your $z\in {\lambda }\cup(\mathbb C \setminus \mathbb R)$ is also true, as I "already stated" indeed. I then derived $z\in\Bbb C\setminus{0,-2}$ from it, whence the desired conclusion $|z^2+2z|^2>0$. The implicit but obvious step in this derivation is: $-2$ and $0$ are not roots of $P$.

From my point of view it just obscures the derivation. But I do not insist on changes to your answer.

Well I answered a similar question here
Let $k$ be an odd integer. Let $A$ be a matrix such that $A^k = A + I$. Prove that $\det(A) > 0$.
where we show that if $A$ is a square matrix satisfying $A^k -A -I =0$; $k$ odd [so $k=19$ will do] then det$(A)$ is positive. We go through the proof here, as it may be instructive in relation to the answers already posted.
We first establish that $\det(A)$ is positive. The thing is, det$(A)$ is of the form
$$\det(A) = \prod^n_i \lambda_i$$ where $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots, \lambda_n$ are the $n$ not necesarily distinct roots [where $n$ is s.t. $A$ is $n×n$] of the polynomial $\det(A -\lambda I)$. Yes indeed, each $\lambda_i$ is indeed a root of $p(X)=X^{19}-X-1$ but the issue is this: we don't a priori have a guarantee for how many times each root of $p(X) = X^{19}-X-1$ appears in the multiset $S=\{\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n\}$. HOWEVER, $\det(A-\lambda I)$ is also a polynomial w real coefficients, so if a complex root $\lambda$ of $p$ appears $j$ times in the multiset $S$, its conjugate $\bar{\lambda}$ also appears the same number $j$ times in $S$. As $(\lambda\bar{\lambda})^j$ is positive real for each integral $j$, it follows then that $\det(A)=\prod^n_i \lambda_i$ indeed positive after all.
Now we establish that $\det(A+2I) =$ $\prod_{i=1}^n (\lambda_i+2)$ is also positive. Indeed, on the one hand, each $i$ s.t. $\lambda_i$ is real satisfies $\lambda_i >0$ [because $\lambda_i$ is a root of $p(x)$] and thus $\lambda_i +2$ $> 0$ as well. On the other hand, if $\lambda$ is a complex root of $p(x)$ such that $\lambda+2$ appears $j$ times in the multiset $S'=$ $\{\lambda_1+2, \ldots, \lambda_i+2\}$, then its complex conjugate $\bar{\lambda}+2$ appears the same number $j$ of times in $S'$. So the same line of reasoning that establishes that $\det(A)$ is positive, also establishes that $\det(A+2I)$ is positive as well.
Then from the facts $A^{19} = A+I$ and in particular $A^{19}-I = A$ and $A^{19}+I =A+2I$, it follows that $$\det(A^{38}-I) = $$ $$\det(A+2I)\det(A).$$ As we have shown $\det(A)$ and $\det(A+2I)$ are both positive, the result follows.
We don't need the fact that $A$ is $3×3$, by the way. Any $n$ will do.

I cannot follow the end of this answer. I know that $\det(A^{38}-I)$ is equal to $\det(A^{19}+I)\det(A^{19}-I)=\det(A^{19}+I)\det(A)$, but what allows you to claim it is equal to $\det(A^{19}-I)\det(A)$, i.e. to $\det(A)^2$?

I never claimed that though, all I claimed is that $\det(A^{19}-I)\det(A)$ is positive.

@AnneBauval as $\det(A^{19}-I)$ and $\det(A)$ are both positive, the former we are given, the latter just established earlier in my answer.

And we are given...$A^{19}-I =A$ so $\det(A^{19}-I) = ,det(A)$.

Yes you did claim that:$$"\det(A^{38}-I) = \det(A^{19}-I)\det(A)" $$so, what justifies it?

@AnneBauval you are correct I finally see the mistake I made. Fixed it!
